# Where does Custom Vision store training images

Tags: python, azure, scripting, microsoft-custom-vision

I developed an Image Classification Model in CustomVision.AI
I want to download all of the training images used to train the model
I used the training API and was able to retrieve the "HTML" location of all the images however I'd like to use a script to actually download the image to a local drive from the HTML location but am not great with writing scripts as much as running them.

I was also trying to figure out if the images are stored in an azure resource or are custom vision uses its own load storage the images, I'd like to move the images over to an azure blob.

I'm not really a "Programmer" really more of a high-level technology manager but I am comfortable in running scripts and some python code.

Comment: Could you solve it with my way?

Answer (score 0):

> I was also trying to figure out if the images are stored in an azure
>   resource

I suppose it's , cause the images are stored in blob after I checked the image uri. You could use browser developer tool(F12) directly to check the picture uri. The uri format is blob url with image id.

If you want to get all images uri you could use this api: [GetTaggedImages](https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Training_3.0/operations/5c771cdcbf6a2b18a0c3b7fc) and [GetUntaggedImages](https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Training_3.0/operations/5c771cdcbf6a2b18a0c3b7fd), it will return all images information including the uri.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response George, I've used the API to generate a json file with all the URLs but they limited to 250 per run I've got over 8,000 total. If I can't locate The blob where there are stored I need a script to go through the json file and basically download each image file, which I'm really not able to do.